# IE BHO screenshot

Tags: api, internet-explorer, documentation, bho

Where would I find the API that I can call from a BHO?

Basically I need to figure out how long will it take to build a screnshot functionality inside IE.

I have done the same research for FF and it was quite easy to find information on how to do it and what sort of API I would have available but now I need to do the same for IE and can't seem to find any information about it. Just the plain old tutorials on how to build a BHO etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) but it still doesn't help regarding the screenshot

Comment: Getting a screen shot isn't browser-specific.  It's a Windows thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got my answers:

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx) is a good start point for the API and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21913/TeboScreen-Basic-C-Screen-Capture-Application) is a good example on how to do a screen shot in C#